# As a part of Vs as part of

Tags: indefinite-article

According to Ngram, **as part of** is more common than **as a part of** but my freelancer who is a native speaker used "a". Do you think "a part" is better than "part" here?

> Given that individuals are spending a considerable portion of their
> lives in the workplace, it is essential for employers to provide
> healthcare and educational benefits as **a** part of their employee
> compensation package, acknowledging their contributions to the
> organization.

Comment: Your freelancer is "atypical". The [vast majority of native Anglophones](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+a+part+of+the%2Cas+part+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) would *not* include that (optional) article before ***part***. But both are "acceptable", so any answers here are Off Topic opinions anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ngram Viewer shows, "as a part of" is 18 times less common [in British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+a+part+of%2Cas+part+of&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=0). [In American English,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+a+part+of%2Cas+part+of&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=0) though, it's somewhat less rare, being "only" 11 times less common.

**To me (in the US), either sounds fine.** But they have slightly different meanings, [for reasons that the Cambridge definition of "part" explains](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/part). As an uncountable noun, "part" means "some but not all of a thing." As a countable noun, it means "a separate piece of something."

So: "as a part of" emphasizes that it is a separate, independent component of the compensation package. "As part of" emphasizes that it is contained within, and forms a portion of, the package.

In British English, though, you may want to avoid "as a part of" entirely, since it seems to be substantially less common there. It appears that the split [between American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+a+part+of+the%2Cas+part+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) and [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+a+part+of+the%2Cas+part+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) on this issue has been around for some time.

Comment: I think ngrams are really dumb for this kind of thing. However, +1 for you "so" paragraph.